# Parallel updating data in Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a problem with parallel updating data in Cosmos DB.

Updating Cosmos Db requires to:

- Get data from the document
- Change data
- Save changed data

The parallel update is a problem because the second thread can get data before the first thread saves changes. Then data from the first three is lost because it is overwritten with the second thread.

See code:

```
public async Task UpdateValue(Dto dto)
{
    var details = new detail(dto.Description, dto.EmployeeName);
    var id = Guid.Parse(dto.SyncId);
    var organizationId = Guid.Parse(dto.OrganizationId);

    var result = await _container
    .GetItemLinqQueryable<Sync>()
    .Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId && x.Id == id)
    .ToFeedIterator()
    .GetOneAsync();

    result.ChangeValues(details);

    await _container
        .ReplaceItemAsync(result, id.ToString(), new PartitionKey(organizationId.ToString()));
}
```

I have successfully solved this with SemaphoreSlim.

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

   public async Task UpdateValue(Dto dto)
    {
        var details = new detail(dto.Description, dto.EmployeeName);
        var id = Guid.Parse(dto.SyncId);
        var organizationId = Guid.Parse(dto.OrganizationId);

        await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            var result = await _container
            .GetItemLinqQueryable<Sync>()
            .Where(x => x.OrganizationId == organizationId && x.Id == id)
            .ToFeedIterator()
            .GetOneAsync();

            result.ChangeValues(details);

            await _container
                .ReplaceItemAsync(result, id.ToString(), new PartitionKey(organizationId.ToString()));
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
    }
```

Now only one thread can update data at the same time. But this does not feel like the best solution. I would not expect to have a problem with parallel updates in CosmosDb. Do you have any advice on what is best practice in a case like this?

Comment: You don’t want other threads to overwrite the data. Is that correct?

Comment: Why are you using a query to look for the document? If you know the id and partition key value, use ReadItemAsync instead.

Comment: Also, you can use Patch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update

Comment: *Now only one thread can update data at the same time. But this does not feel like the best solution. I would not expect to have a problem with parallel updates in CosmosDb.* I wonder, what **did** you expect?

Comment: @PeterBons I would expect that you can update the same document in the same local partition from different regions and different microservices. And that CosmosDb is smart enough to resolve those conflicts. The case that I have is much simpler.

Comment: @GauravMantri I want it to behave the same as if it were not parallel.

Answer (score 1):

A few options that behaves differenty

1. Push your updates through 1 by 1
2. Let things run in parallel and implement optimistic concurrency control(OCC) and retry in case of a clash, more info on OCC can be found [here](https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/10-concurrency-control.html)

3. Use some sort of queue system like EventHubs etc that can guarantee sequencing etc if thats needed.